# Attribute in lightning component is failing to evaluate properly in conditionals

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute, aura-if

I am unsure of what I am missing here...

So I have a child component with an attribute:

`<aura:attribute name="recordClosed" type="Boolean" />`

In the component I am doing something like this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.recordData}" var="recordField">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!recordField.isDescription == false || (recordField.isDescription &amp;&amp; v.recordClosed == false)}">
        <lightning:layout>
            <!--some html-->
        </lightning:layout>
    </aura:if>
</aura:iteration>
```

The problem is with recordClosed. In my parent, I pass in the value for recordClosed when I create the component.

Now, if I add `{!v.recordClosed}` above the aura:if, it will print out 'false' on in my component. If I do {!v.recordClosed == false}, it will still spit out false... So my aura:if is failing when it should be true.

It says the value for `recordField.isDescription` is true and `recordClosed` is false, but the `recordClosed` comparison fails. It even does it when it is true and compared to true.

I even tried using `{!not(v.recordClosed)}`, it still fails to spit out true even though recordClosed is false.

Comment: Does this work- `{!and(recordField.isDescription, !v.recordClosed)}`, not sure if it does some kind of type check (which would be rather odd). Otherwise try with adding `default="true"` to the attribute. If nothing works, kindly share minimal code for us to replicate the behavior.

Comment: I ended up finally figuring out the issue. How I was grabbing the value to pass to recordClosed was actually ending up converting it to a String type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like I wasn't going back far enough to diagnose the issue.

My parent component constructs anchor elements with data attributes, which is where I was storing my value for recordClosed:

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-isclosed="{!data.isClosed}" onclick="{!c.createChild}"></a>`

Then when that was clicked, I would get isclosed attribute doing `event.target.dataset.isclosed` and was passing that to my child component when I created it.

Turns out, doing it this way ends up converting the type of isclosed to String. So I was passing a string to the Boolean attribute in my child, causing it to not know how to compare it.